# O modo r+ em C para arquivos não cria o arquivo caso não exista?

Tags: c

Estou trabalhano neste código abaixo e gostaria de armazenar alguns vetores aleatórios em um arquivo. Pelo oque eu li o modo r+ lê o arquivo e escreve nele, e caso ele não exista será criado. Bem...Acontece que quando uso o código na maneira que está ele não consegue criar um arquivo, simplesmente entra na condicional que define um erro ao criar o arquivo, porém quando mudo o modo de "r+" para "w+", ele cria o arquivo e funciona direitinho, gostaria de saber se oque eu li a respeito do "r+" está errado ou é algo que está errado no meu programa e eu não estou vendo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define tam 1000000

int main (){
    //declaração de variáveis
    FILE * arq = NULL;
    int i,array_size,v[tam];

    //lendo o tamanho do vetor e a quatidade de vetores a serem gerado
    printf("Digite o tamanho do vetor a ser gerado : \n");
    scanf ("%d",&array_size);

    //criando arquivo para armazenar os vetores gerados
    arq = fopen("vetoresgerados","r+");
    if (arq == NULL){
        printf ("Erro ao abrir o aquivo\n");
        return 0;
    }

    //gerando vetores aleatórios
    srand (time(0));
    for (i = 0; i < array_size;i++){
        v[i] = rand()%1000;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < array_size;i++){
        fprintf(arq, "%d ",v[i]);
    }
    fclose(arq);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `"r+"` Abre o arquivo para leitura e atualizacao
>
> `"w+"` Abre o arquivo para escrever e atualicao, se o arquivo nao existir ele cria.

Referencia: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/